# '80s or '90s animated series involving heroes who would ride on space gliders

Tags: story-identification, space, animated-series

I'm looking to find an old cartoon that aired in the 80's weekdays after 2 or 3 PM East coast NYC.

From what I can remember the show had 3 or 4 heroes that would ride on some kind of space gliders. They fought mostly in space.  The closes think I can think of is the Power Rangers' Galaxy Gliders.
I think they had armor kinda like the [*"Ronin Warriors"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronin_Warriors) and they fought with some sort of staff weapons.
The leader was always yelling "heyahooo!"

Comment: Was this on TV?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you tell us a bit more about what the main characters looked like? (Like how many were male or female, what colours they wore, whether they wore helmets or armour, etc.) Also, when you say they rode on the gliders, can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by that? Was it like riding a surfboard? Like using a hand-glider? Something else?

Comment: I can't remember to much about it.
I think they had armor kinda like the Ronin Warriors and they fought with some sort of staff.
The closes think I can think of is the Power Rangers galaxy Gliders.
So it was a cartoon that aired in the 80's weekdays after 2 or 3 PM East coast NYC.

Answer (score 7):

This could be [*"Starzinger"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starzinger) (also known as *"Force Five: Spaceketeers"* in the USA).

The series originally aired in Japan in 1978, and in the following years it was distributed and dubbed worlwide.

The story follows space princess Aurora in her mission to reach the Great Planet, bringing back peace and restoring balance in the galaxy. She is protected by three humanoid cyborgs, color-themed in red, blue and green, who often pilot (or stand on) small flying vehicles.

The red cyborg fights using a <strike>magical</strike> technologically advanced extendable staff, the blue one wields a trident, the green one has a mace.

You can see Princess Aurora and the cyborgs in this image:

[image: the three cyborgs and their flying vehicles]

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[Skysurfer Strike Force](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0211867/)*** (1995-1996)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skysurfer_Strike_Force):

> *Skysurfer Strike Force* is a science-fiction superhero animated series that was featured on Bohbot Entertainment's Amazin' Adventures cartoon block and was co-produced by Ruby-Spears Productions and Ashi Productions. The show lasted two seasons (13 episodes for each season) in the mid-1990s. The first episode (first episode of the first season) aired on September 10, 1995, and the last episode (final episode of the second season) was on October 26, 1996. The show then aired in reruns on the Sci Fi Channel in 1999 through 2000. It was the final creation of Ruby-Spears Productions before shutting down.

From IMDB:

> Jack Holister is an extraordinary skydiver who leads a group of vigilante crime fighters known as the Skysurfer Strike Force. Jack's mission is to seek out and defeat the robotic Cybron - a man with a computer for a brain who may have played a sinister role in the mysterious death of Jack's scientist father. **The Skysurfers battle Cybron using anti-gravity skyboards that fly on their own rocket power. This group of daredevils soars the skies at breakneck speeds and performs amazing acrobatic feats in their battle for justice.**